# Create object from select values React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The intention is to choose topping, base and size and then once click 'Submit', pizza should appear on the top of the table, above select drop downs.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Container, Table } from 'reactstrap'
import AppNavbar from './AppNavbar'
import newOrderColumnsData from './columns/NewOrderColumnsData'

export default function NewOrder() {

  const [error, setError] = useState('')
  const [toppings, setToppings] = useState([])
  const [sizes, setSizes] = useState([])
  const [bases, setBases] = useState([])
  const [topping, setTopping] = useState('')
  const [base, setBase] = useState('')
  const [size, setSize] = useState('')
  const [pizzaList, setPizzaList] = useState([])

  const addPizza = () => {
    const newPizza = {
      toppingId: topping,
      pizzaSize: size,
      pizzaBase: base,
    };

    const newPizzas = [...pizzaList, newPizza];

    setPizzaList(newPizzas);
    setTopping('');
    setBase('');
    setSize('');
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/pizza/toppings")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setToppings(data))
      .catch((error) => setError(error.message))

    fetch("/pizza/bases")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setBases(data))
      .catch((error) => setError(error.message))

    fetch("/pizza/sizes")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setSizes(data))
      .catch((error) => setError(error.message))
  }, [])


    return (
        <div>
          <AppNavbar />
          <Container fluid>
            <h1 className="row justify-content-center">Create your order:</h1>
            <Table bordered hover>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  {newOrderColumnsData.map((column) => (
                    <th key={column.key} width="25%">
                      {column.label}
                    </th>
                   ))}
                </tr>
              </thead>
      <tbody>
          {pizzaList.map((pizza) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{pizza.toppingId}</td>
              <td>{pizza.pizzaSize.pizzaSizeId}</td>
              <td>{pizza.pizzaBase.pizzaBaseId}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select onChange={(event) => setTopping(event.target.value)}>
              {toppings.map((topping) => {return <option key={topping.toppingId} value={topping.toppingId}>{topping.toppingName}</option>})}
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select onChange={(event) => setSize(event.target.value)}>
              {sizes.map((size) => {return <option key={size.pizzaSizeId} value={size}>{size.pizzaSize}</option>})}
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select onChange={(event) => setBase(event.target.value)}>
              {bases.map((base) => {return <option key={base.pizzaBaseId} value={base}>{base.pizzaBaseName}</option>})}
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
            </Table>
            <button onClick={() => addPizza()}>
      Submit
    </button>
        </Container>
    </div>
)
}
```

This code works, however i need to be able to save order in the database, for which i need to be passing toppingId, baseId and sizeId to request body. Is it possible to return object as value from  or what would be the correct approach here?

UPD:
Changed addPizza function like this:

```
const addPizza = () => {
  const topping = toppings.find((topping) => topping.toppingId == toppingId);
  const size = sizes.find((size) => size.pizzaSizeId == sizeId);
  const base = bases.find((base) => base.pizzaBaseId == baseId);

  const newPizza = {
    topping: topping,
    pizzaSize: size,
    pizzaBase: base,
  };

  setPizzaList(pizzaList => [...pizzaList, newPizza]);
  setToppingId('');
  setBaseId('');
  setSizeId('');
}
```

For some reason newPizza get created correctly, but pizzaList is always empty.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. You want to call your API with toppingId, baseId and sizeId ? What do you mean by "return object as value from" ?

Comment: So for example topping contains id and name, when i select it from dropdown, it should be added to of pizza, not only id. Same for base and size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search in your toppings or bases or sizes with id and then set your pizza state like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Container, Table } from 'reactstrap'
import AppNavbar from './AppNavbar'
import newOrderColumnsData from './columns/NewOrderColumnsData'

export default function NewOrder() {

  const [error, setError] = useState('')
  const [toppings, setToppings] = useState([]);
  const [sizes, setSizes] = useState([]);
  const [bases, setBases] = useState([]);
  const [toppingId, setToppingId] = useState('');
  const [baseId, setBaseId] = useState('');
  const [sizeId, setSizeId] = useState('');
  const [pizzaList, setPizzaList] = useState([]);

  const addPizza = () => {
    const topping = toppings.filter((topping) => tppping.toppingId === toppingId);
    const size = sizes.filter((size) => size.pizzaSizeId === sizeId);
    const base = bases.filter((base) => base.pizzaBaseId === baseId);
    const newPizza = {
      topping: topping,
      pizzaSize: size,
      pizzaBase: base,
    };

    const newPizzas = [...pizzaList, newPizza];

    setPizzaList(newPizzas);
    setTopping('');
    setBase('');
    setSize('');
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/pizza/toppings")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setToppings(data))
      .catch((error) => setError(error.message))

    fetch("/pizza/bases")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setBases(data))
      .catch((error) => setError(error.message))

    fetch("/pizza/sizes")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setSizes(data))
      .catch((error) => setError(error.message))
  }, [])


  return (
      <div>
        <AppNavbar />
          <Container fluid>
            <h1 className="row justify-content-center">Create your order:</h1>
            <Table bordered hover>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  {newOrderColumnsData.map((column) => (
                    <th key={column.key} width="25%">
                      {column.label}
                    </th>
                   ))}
                </tr>
              </thead>
      <tbody>
          {pizzaList.map((pizza) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{pizza.topping.toppingName}</td>
              <td>{pizza.size.pizzaSize}</td>
              <td>{pizza.base.pizzaBaseName}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select onChange={(event) => setTopping(event.target.value)}>
              {toppings.map((topping) => {return <option key={topping.toppingId} value={topping.toppingId}>{topping.toppingName}</option>})}
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select onChange={(event) => setSize(event.target.value)}>
              {sizes.map((size) => {return <option key={size.pizzaSizeId} value={size.pizzaSizeId}>{size.pizzaSize}</option>})}
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select onChange={(event) => setBase(event.target.value)}>
              {bases.map((base) => {return <option key={base.pizzaBaseId} value={base.pizzaBaseId}>{base.pizzaBaseName}</option>})}
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
            </Table>
            <button onClick={() => addPizza()}>
      Submit
    </button>
        </Container>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I put updates on the initial post regarding your suggestions

Comment: When you log pizzaList, it shows an empty array ?